# If today's date is Saturday, Sunday, or Monday then set today's date to last Friday, else set to today in R

Tags: r

**With only** the `System Libraries` (preferably), how do I set today's date to last Friday if today falls on Saturday, Sunday, or Monday, else set to today's date?

```
todaysDate <- Sys.Date()

if(weekdays(todaysDate) == "Saturday" || weekdays(todaysDate) == "Sunday" 
   || weekdays(todaysDate) == "Monday") {
  todaysDate == ???} else {
    todaysDate <- Sys.Date()
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

---

Systems used:

- R version: 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
- RStudio version: 1.4.1717
- OS: macOS Catalina version 10.15.7 and macOS Big Sur version 11.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do this with `match` on sequence of dates before the 'todaysDate' that matches the 'Friday'

```
if(weekdays(todaysDate) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday")) {
      s1 <- todaysDate - (1:8)
      todaysDate <- s1[match('Friday', weekdays(s1))]
    }
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks akrun!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the logic:

```
todaysDate <- Sys.Date()
today <- weekdays(todaysDate)

if(today == "Saturday")
  todaysDate <- todaysDate - 1
else if (today == "Sunday") 
   todaysDate <- todaysDate - 2
else if (today == "Monday") 
   todaysDate <- todaysDate - 3
```

Answer (score 1):

An other solution might be a recursive function:

```r
dayFun <- function(x) {
  if (weekdays(x) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday")) {
    return(dayFun(x-1))
  } else {
    return(x)
  }
}
dayFun(Sys.Date())
```

note that the result of `weekdays` depends on the language setting of the machine so if that is a concern some more thoughts are needed

Comment: Thank you for your solution. However, when I tried it out today, it worked with ```todaysDate <- Sys.Date()``` (i.e., 2021-10-05), but it gave me an ```Error: C stack usage  7969664 is too close to the limit``` when I set ```todaysDate <- Sys.Date()-1``` (i.e., 2021-10-04). The same error occurred with 2021-10-03 and 2021-10-02, but worked with 2021-10-01 (i.e., ```todaysDate <- Sys.Date()-4```) if ```Sys.Date()``` = 2021-10-05.

Comment: Was this solved by fixing the typo in the date name?

Comment: With the typo corrected it indeed works. Thank you.